# Azure Tables advanced queries

Tags: c#, performance, azure-table-storage

I read somewhere that querying the data for other than RowKey and PartitionKey will result in a full table scan. I am looking to properly understand the whole query process, but I have come up a bit empty on the whole ordeal.

Say I have a few million row's of data objects in a single storage. I have it divided into subsets of data by PartitionKey. Say I create a query along the lines of

```
var query = new TableQuery<MyEntity>()
    .Where(TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, pPartition),
        TableOperators.And,
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, startTime));
```

How is this query constructed on the tables end? Do I have control over which filter is applied first - is it the order of applying them, so in this case I would first get a subset of say.. 100k rows and then apply the Timestamp filter.

The reason I am contemplating this to begin with is that I want to use both the PartitionKey and RowKey to store different data for separation, but I also need to be able to query by date as efficiently as possible. The system will have fairly heavy work load with a lot of requests like this so it is important that it works in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the queries againts TableStorage apply the PatitionKey and th RowKey filter first then for each chunk the additional filters are applied. If you want to improve the performance of queries by some other fields you need to include them as part of the PartitionKey or the RowKey. This is the only way to do that. You may find some advanced technique to do Joins in the PartitionKey and RowKey properties and retrieve them from the TableStorage.